# ReactJs: Simple render table not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a table from data i get via an ajax call. Here is the code:

```js
let tableResult = null;
let tableRows = null;

if(this.state.searchResult === 'records-found') {

  tableRows = this.state.transactionsData.content.map((item, index) => {
    let date = new Date(item.dateOfPayment);
    return (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{date}</td>
        <td>{item.transactionReference}</td>
        <td>{item.merchantCustomerId}</td>
        <td>{item.amount}</td>
        <td>{item.status}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  tableResult = (
    <div className="transactions-table-wrapper">
      <div className="transactions-table">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Date Of Payment</td>
              <td>Merchant Reference</td>
              <td>Customer Id</td>
              <td>Amount</td>
              <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {tableRows}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then table gets rendered like so:

```js
    <div className="transitions-search-result">
      {tableResult}
    </div>
```

The error I get is "Cannot read property 'content' of null" but I print the state before that line. The value is set

Comment: Where are you setting your state? (specifically transactionsData)

Comment: In an ajax call. When there is a response, I call "setState()". This calls the render function( I checked) and the data gets set properly(also checked). When i set a brakepoint and step through the code the line with the error gets executed

Comment: If i step i get this error: " Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Invalid Date). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `SubTransactions`."

Comment: Well..ajax is async. React is probably calling your component's `render` function before your ajax request is done (meaning at that time your state isn't set the way you want). Do you have an initial state in your component (i.e.: do you set `this.state = ...` on your component's `constructor`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your {date} statement.  In your looping of the content collection, you set date = to a new javascript date.  Then in the return, you set one td's value to that date.

React can not render a date object.  You need to make it a string or valid react component.

```
tableRows = this.state.transactionsData.content.map((item, index) => {
    **let date = new Date(item.dateOfPayment);**
    return (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        **<td>{date.toString()}</td>**
        <td>{item.transactionReference}</td>
        <td>{item.merchantCustomerId}</td>
        <td>{item.amount}</td>
        <td>{item.status}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
```

all browsers should support  [date.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

And maybe better would be [date.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString).  Depending if you want to format it our not.

Comment: Damn. Thanks a lot bro. Funny thing is there was no warning. The tableResult object was even looking like a react Object. But rendered null